# Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular

I was getting an object that contained an array of objects by making an HTTP call in my angular app. I want to display them via this HTML:

```
          <div class="row text-white">
            <div class="col-6">
              <h4 class="pt-1 m-0 text-white">
                <ng-container *ngIf="optionsForVideoPostGraph && optionsForVideoPostGraph.series">
                  <i style="font-size: 2vw;" class="fa fa-male"></i>
                  <span>{{ optionsForVideoPostGraph?.series[0]?.data.pop() }}</span>
                  <br> Total Male user <br>
                  <i style="font-size: 2vw;" class="fa fa-female"></i>
                  <span>{{ optionsForVideoPostGraph?.series[1]?.data.pop() }}</span>
                </ng-container>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 text-right pl-0">
              <span>{{ optionsForVideoPostGraph?.series[2]?.data.pop() }}</span>
              <br />
              <span>Total</span>
            </div>
          </div>
```

The variable `optionsForVideoPostGraph` looks like :
[[image: response1]

The HTTP call was done inside the ngOnit lifecycle hook. What have I done wrong here?

Comment: To roughly explain the error, angular during development throws in extra checks to make sure the template doesn’t change after it checks it in a certain order (unidirectional data flow). Likely the nested pop which causes changes to containing template (parent within the same template) bindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because you are calling `pop()` within your template, since `pop()` removes the last element from the array. You'll need to access the last element in a different way.

The simplest way to do this is probably:

```
{{ optionsForVideoPostGraph?.series[0]?.data[optionsForVideoPostGraph.series[0].data.length] }}
```